# HTML menubar with screen resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create menu bar

Everything seem to be ok when it full screen but when

its browser width size is smaller than menubar

content in menu bar become in a new line

instead of continue in a line with scroll bar

What should I do

Here is my html

```
<div class="menuBar">
    <div class="navigate">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hotel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Airfare</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Package</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tour guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its better if you provide your CSS code with your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `min-width` style to your `ul` wrapper, for exmp.

```
.navigate{
   min-width: 800px;
}
```